# Polymer 1.0 app routing, load external pages inside div

Tags: html, css, angularjs, polymer-1.0

I searched many tutorials and all documentation about App router, I have tried the guide at https://erikringsmuth.github.io/app-router/ but I do not understand how I can load an HTML page inside a div, without the other reloaded. I know this is make it with AJAX, but with polymer that is different, how could do ?. This is the code for my index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-menu/paper-submenu.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-collapse/iron-collapse.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/typography.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-request.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/app-router/app-router.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/pushstate-anchor/pushstate-anchor.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Reino Unido</title>
</head>

<body>
    <paper-drawer-panel>
        <div drawer class="menu">
            <paper-toolbar class="drawer">
                <span>Reino Unido</span>
            </paper-toolbar>
            <paper-menu class="list">
                <paper-item>
                    <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon><span class="Menu"><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></span></paper-item>
                <paper-item>
                    <iron-icon icon="shopping-cart"></iron-icon><span class="Menu"><a href="#/catalogo">Catálogo</a></span></paper-item>
                <paper-item>
                    <iron-icon icon="star"></iron-icon><span class="Menu"><a href="#/promociones.html">Promociones</a></span></paper-item>
                <paper-item>
                    <iron-icon icon="drafts"></iron-icon><span class="Menu"><a href="#/contacto.html">Contáctanos</a></span></paper-item>
                <paper-item>
                    <iron-icon icon="info"></iron-icon><span class="Menu">Acerca de</span></paper-item>
            </paper-menu>
        </div>
        <div main class="page">
            <paper-toolbar class="main">
                <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                <span title class="flex">Inicio</span>
                <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
            </paper-toolbar>
            <div id="sections">

                Here I want to load HTML pages
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </paper-drawer-panel>
    <app-router>
        <app-route path="/catalogo" import="catalogo.html"></app-route>
    </app-router>
</body>

</html>
```

And the app, looks like:

[Screnshoot of the App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84rDJ.png)

Comment: You can create webcomponent of this pages..

Comment: Create the pages like a webcomponent and then call the custom component inside de div?

Comment: yes,I think this is the solution

Comment: It's a good solution, thanks¡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create every page as a web component and then put the custom element tag inside the div.
This way will save your code very clean and understandable.